# How to unpack dd file on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, dd

Is it possible to unpack files created with linux dd tool on Windows?
I have tried that tool http://www.chrysocome.net/dd, but it crashes under Windows 7.
Any ideas?

Comment: `dd` is a rather low-level tool and there are many ways it could be used. How exactly did you create those files?

Comment: Please Consider marking your own answer below as correct.

Answer (score 3):

`dd` doesn't "pack" anything.  It just literally copies.   For example:

```
dd if=/path/sometextfile.txt of=whatever.file
```

"whatever.file" will be *identical* to "sometextfile.txt".

However, `dd` can be used to copy directly from the block layer of a device:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=disk.img
```

In which case you again have a literal copy.  Presuming they are done correctly from a device containing an actual filesystem, windows *may* be able to do something with these if you give them an `.iso` suffix, but it probably won't work if the underlying filesystem was ext.

Another good reason *not* to use `dd` as a method of backing up filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a tool which allows to mount *.dd files as Windows virtual drives:
http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html
That is all I needed.